# How to print linked list in reverse order?

Tags: c++

I try to make linked list in c++.
I want to write a method which should read linked list in reverse order.
I don't want to change argument in method.
My problem is a recursion, I don't know what should I get there.
In my opinion stack is a great idea.
My code:

```
void  reverse(List* list) {
    Node * wsk = list->first;
    if (list->first == NULL) {
        return;
    } else if (wsk->next != NULL) {
        reverse(list); // reverse(?)
    }
    cout << wsk->value << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a helper function that traverses the nodes of the linked list and prints them in reverse order.

```
void  reverse_nodes(Node* node) {
   if ( node != NULL )
   {
      reverse_nodes(node->next);
      cout << node->value << endl;
   }
}
```

and call it from the function that is called with the list.

```
void  reverse(List* list) {
   reverse_nodes(list->first);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I used that code but cLion is throwing: Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD) // It can be problem with my List?

Comment: @Chris23329, that's the only reason I can think of.